# std::fstream taking very long time to write large data into .csv file

Tags: c++, c++11, io

I am trying to write the large data into a csv file and the number of rows I am dealing with is in Millions.

My code is generating the rows in form of array of doubles. The code is taking vary long time to write data into file (double than writing the same number of records to database with 10k bulk insert on the same machine).

I have tried buffering the 10000 and 100000 rows in the std::string but it is still slow.

```
HRESULT FastLoad::Insert()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= m_iCsvColumnCount; i++)  // m_iCsvColumnCount is actual number of columns 1 to n
    {
        if (arrayOfRowVals[i] != NULL_NUM)    // arrayOfRowVals is array of double 
        m_Csvfile << arrayOfRowVals[i];       // std::fstream  m_Csvfile.open("/install/FactPOC/Fact.csv", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);

        if (i < m_iCsvColumnCount)
        {
            m_Csvfile << ",";
        }
    }
    m_Csvfile << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= m_nColumnCount; i++)` likely an off by 1 error. Arrays in `c++` have indicies of 0 .. size -1

Comment: Write directly to the file instead of creating a string for the entire line and then writing that.

Comment: Unless you are doing some funky processing (you're not), it is often simpler AND faster to write data directly to the file instead of writing to a buffer and then outputting the buffer.  Most output streams do their own buffering and, odds are, that is designed with knowledge of the implementation (compiler, likely hosts, etc). Also, array indexing in C++ is zero-based, so you probably have an off-by-one error giving undefined behaviour - which can manifest in many ways, including strange performance concerns.

Comment: for a code review you might rather try at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Just make sure to post correct and complete code there

Comment: Write a few rows to a `char` array, then use `std::ostream::write()` to write the array.  Repeat.  Adjust the size of the array for efficiency, such as multiples of 512 bytes.

Comment: You can also use multiple buffers and threads.  One thread writes to a buffer and fills it up.  It starts filling up the second buffer.  The output thread starts writing the first buffer, then will write the second buffer.  Use as many buffers to adjust the timing.

Comment: Use raw API to flush data to disk in fast way. Default stream is not designed for velocity but for conformity.

Comment: @lsalamon That's a myth.

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the file over and over and over and over and over again. That's bound to be slow!!

Instead, open it *once*. Give the function a reference to your `ifstream` that it can re-use.

And drop the buffering. There are already plenty of existing, better layers of buffering between you and the filesystem.

Comment: Just tried exactly what you said, eliminated reopening and buffering part, but now it is taking more time than earlier. seems I will need to buffer the data in some other efficient way.

Comment: Are you building a release executable with optimizations turned on?

Comment: That does not make sense.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I am doing it with -O2 option.